# Is it possible to emulate ARM on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, arm, emulation, raspberry-pi, hyper-v

I'd like to run [Raspbian](http://www.raspbian.org/) in a virtual machine on Windows 8.  It is built for the ARM processor on a [Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/).

Is this possible?

Comment: Why the close vote?  I can rephrase the question if you think it needs changing.

Comment: @AhmedMasud Aye, but but all I get were references to Windows compatibility to run on an ARM processor.  I have just played with different keywords though and found [qEmu][http://wiki.qemu.org/Download] which looks promising.

Comment: Yes I searched on google and this appears as the first search result.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a tutorial on how to run Raspberry Pi under windows using QEMU:

http://cubik-tech.blogspot.ca/2013/02/raspberry-pi-emulation-on-windows.html

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like I'm looking in the right place now, thanks.